# Unity3d RotateTowards only on z axis

Tags: unity-game-engine, rotation, quaternions

I have GameObject that I need to rotate arouns Z axis. It needs to face the cursor all the time. But it rotates on all axis. Here is the code:

```
Vector3 mouseClickPos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
Vector3 dir = mouseClickPos - transform.position;
Vector3 h1dir = Vector3.RotateTowards(hand1.transform.forward, dir, 6.0f, 1.0f);
hand1.transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(h1dir);
```

Comment: The direction of motion has been set to the vector difference of the positions of the `mouseClickPos` and `transform.position`. This would result in a 3-dimensional vector and hence your object rotates in all directions.

Comment: What do i need to do to make it rotate only on z axis?

Comment: I am not fully competent to giving you the correct code. But what I can understand is that you should ignore the `z-axis` co-ordinates when calculating the direction vector. The direction of the vector difference of the `x-axis` and `y-axis` values is where the object should be facing.
Imagine looking at the object from the top. Now the `z` value of the mouse pointer is useless. The object is in the direction of the mouse pointer when viewed from above, hence only the `x` and `y` co-ordinates come into play.